# Angular UI-Bootstrap Tooltip on Checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a checkbox that I am trying to get so that it will show a tooltip when you check the checkbox, but not show the tooltip if you do not have the checkbox checked. Here is the markup:

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-checkbox"
        ng-model="isPublic"
        uib-tooltip="Only show me if checkbox is checked"
        tooltip-placement="top-left"
        tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"
        uib-btn-checkbox>
            <span class="glyphicons ok_2" ng-show="isPublic"></span>
</button>
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score -1):

I would try a function that will populate you $scope.myTooltip:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheckbox" ng-change="setTooltip()" id="ng-change-example1" />

...
uib-tooltip="{{myTooltip}}"
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.setTooltip = function() {
    if($scope.myCheckbox.checked) {
        $scope.myTooltip = 'my Text';
    } else {
        $scope.myTooltip = '';
    }
};
```